# Javascript how to filter a list with category and subcategories

Tags: javascript, html, list, filter

**UPDATE (Nov 2019):** Like [@Austin T French](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47426181/javascript-how-to-filter-a-list-with-category-and-subcategories/47426297#47426297) mentioned below, the key is to make sure to differentiate (ie. group) the countries by `class` for example. Updated code snippet added below!

---

In the code below is it possible to filter the list of "countries" (subcategories) so that the "continent" (parent category) filters as well?

For example if I search "China" I want to have "Asia" filter above it at the same time.

As a next step I'd also like to have the "subcategories" display when search for the "parent categories". For example, when searching for "Asia" I want to have "China", "Japan", and "South Korea" to filter.

Or would this be more practical to create a filtered table with two columns?

```js
function filterCountries() {
  var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
  input = document.getElementById("search-country");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  ul = document.getElementById("country-list");
  li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
  for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Countries</h2>

<input type="text" id="search-country" onkeyup="filterCountries()" placeholder="Search for countries.." title="Type in a country">

<ul id="country-list">
  <li><a href="#"><strong>Asia</strong></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">China</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">South Korea</a></li>

  <li><a href="#"><strong>Europe</strong></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">France</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li>

  <li><a href="#"><strong>North America</strong></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Mexico</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">United States</a></li>

  <li><a href="#"><strong>South America</strong></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Argentina</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Brazil</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Chile</a></li>
</ul>
```

---

**UPDATED CODE (Nov 2019)**

```js
function filterCountries() {
  const input = document.getElementById("search-country");
  const filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  const li = document.querySelectorAll("li");
  for (let i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    const a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];
    if (a.textContent.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
      document.getElementsByClassName(li[i].className)[0].style.display = "";
      li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
      li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Countries</h2>

<input type="text" id="search-country" onkeyup="filterCountries()" placeholder="Search 
for countries.." title="Type in a country">

<ul class="country-list">
  <li class="asia"><a href="#"><strong>Asia</strong></a></li>
  <li class="asia"><a href="#">China</a></li>
  <li class="asia"><a href="#">Japan</a></li>
  <li class="asia"><a href="#">South Korea</a></li>

  <li class="europe"><a href="#"><strong>Europe</strong></a></li>
  <li class="europe"><a href="#">France</a></li>
  <li class="europe"><a href="#">Germany</a></li>
  <li class="europe"><a href="#">United Kingdom</a></li>

  <li class="north-am"><a href="#"><strong>North America</strong></a></li>
  <li class="north-am"><a href="#">Canada</a></li>
  <li class="north-am"><a href="#">Mexico</a></li>
  <li class="north-am"><a href="#">United States</a></li>

  <li class="south-am"><a href="#"><strong>South America</strong></a></li>
  <li class="south-am"><a href="#">Argentina</a></li>
  <li class="south-am"><a href="#">Brazil</a></li>
  <li class="south-am"><a href="#">Chile</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't currently have any actual method to differentiate regions. I'd add a property to the HTML and optionally select off of that:

```js
function ShowAsia(){
  $(".asia").toggle();
}

function ShowEurope(){
  $(".europe").toggle();
}
```

```css
li {list-style:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" class='asia' style="display: inline;">China</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='asia' style="display: inline;">Japan</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='asia' style="display: inline;">South Korea</a></li>

<li><a href="#" class='europe' style="display: inline;">France</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='europe' style="display: inline;">Germany</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class='europe' style="display: inline;">United Kingdom</a></li>

</ul>

<button type="button" onclick='ShowAsia()'>Show Asia</button>
<button type="button" onclick='ShowEurope()'>Show Europe</button>
```